How to pass null as type string to Generic Method
trying to write a unit test for a generic method. Having trouble passing null as a string to test a case.
tried to pass as value as string
unit test returns "Unable to determine type arguments for method"
Edit: added minimal reproducible example.
namespace Test
{
    partial class MainClass
    {

        public TValue GetValueFrom<TValue>(string value)
        {
            return (TValue)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(TValue));
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    class MainTestClass
    {
        MainClass sut = new();
        [Test]
        [TestCaseSource(nameof(TestCases))]
        public void TestMethod<T>(string passedValue, T expectedValue)
        {
            var result = sut.GetValueFrom<T>(passedValue);
            result.Should().Be(expectedValue);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> TestCases
        {
            get
            {
                yield return new TestCaseData(string.Empty, default(string));
                yield return new TestCaseData("", default(string));
                yield return new TestCaseData(" ", default(string));
            }
        }
    }
}

Edit2:
the reason TypeArgs  isn't the answer for me is because the testcasedata is structed in this way;
public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> TestCases
    {
        get
        {
            var defaultValues = new List<object>
            {
                default(DateTime),
                default(string),
                default(int)
            };

            foreach (var value in defaultValues)
            {
                yield return new TestCaseData(string.Empty, value);
                yield return new TestCaseData("", value);
                yield return new TestCaseData(" ", value);
            }
        }
    }


Can you post a [mcve] or at least something that compiles with your error?

Related: https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/3576

@nvoigt added code that can work and reproduce same issue.

It looks like TestCaseData has a TypeArgs property (https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/TestCaseData.html). Try that? new TestCaseData("", null) { TypeArgs = typeof(string) }

The docs for the feature canton7 linked to are here: Sources for generic methods using TestCaseData. The type should be specified through the TestCaseData,TypeArgs property , eg new TestCaseData("",default(string){ TypeArgs = new[] { typeof(string) } };

@PanagiotisKanavos thank you for the information, it is not applicable to this part as explain in original question with edit 2.

There's no other way to specify the type. If you want TestMethod to be generic, you have to use NUnit 4.1 and specify the type through the TypeArgs property which is always available. You'll have to change your TestCases code to include TypeArgs

Why do you want TestMethod to be generic anyway? Especially for parsing, where different types require very different tests. Parsing 123 into an int is almost trivial. Parsing decimals or worse, dates, is guaranteed to fail for different locales. Convert.ChangeType along with all Parse and Format methods accept a CultureInfo object so parsing isn't left to chance

@Wince — excuse me, where can I see null in your code samples?
